# Problems about "cycles/byte" change to "MB/s" when measuring AES speed

Tags: performance, encryption, aes, cpu

I am reading the AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) article (see  http://cr.yp.to/aes-speed/aesspeed-20080926.pdf)

They measure the encryption speed using "Cycles/byte", as I know, if the CPU is known, I can calculate this "Cycles/byte" to "MB/s" by "(number of processors × processor_utilization × processor clock frequency) / Throughput rate in bytes per second or transaction per second = cycles per Byte"

My question is what if I am using a four core Intel CPU, how should I calculate how many processors I am using or these four cores are treated as "one CPU". It seems like they cannot be treated as one CPU because a old CPU with 3.0 GHz will run faster than 2.2GHz dual core CPU then.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on whether you're actually using all four cores (e.g., with multi-threaded code) or just one (single-threaded code). If you don't know otherwise, chances are that it's single-threaded. Also note, however, that most modern processors are superscalar, so they can execute more than one instruction per clock cycle (around 1.8 is fairly typical).

Comment: Well, thank you for your answering, here are the further questions:
1. according to your comment, if I just download the program from crypto++ and run the test for AES, the result is not the "fastest" speed on my PC because probably there are there cores not working on this. But if it is a single-threaded program itself, a 2.0GHz 4-core CPU will probably run slower than a 3.0GHz single core CPU? (maybe there are other factors like caches...) 
2. about the superscalar, how can I know exactly the superscalar factor so I can calculate an accurate result of the speed in "Cycles/byte"?

Comment: 1) Probably true (but I haven't looked at Crypto++ recently enough to say for sure). 2) if the cores are similar otherwise, then maybe. If the cores are different, all bets are off, and if you're saturating the bandwidth to memory, the CPU speed usually won't make any real difference. 3) about the only way to know for a particular CPU is to test (preferably on the target workload).